# How to resolve error: "Couldn't modify partition map because file system verification failed"?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I upgraded to Lion and decided I no longer want 100 GB of my drive devoted to Boot Camp, I never boot into Windows, I just use it as a VM anyways. So I deleted the boot camp partition using disk utility and then attempted to expand the main partition to fill this now unallocated space. I also deleted the boot camp from inside VMWare Fusion. When I go to expand it, I get the error in the title of this question.

After searching this forum and Google, I found a lot of people with similar problems but none receiving this exact error with any resolution. I do not want to do a clean install if at all possible. I have enabled debug mode in Disk Utility and tried other stuff, but to no avail.

I've tried editing it in normal and in debug mode while running Lion, and I've tried in recovery mode.

Here are screenshots of the error and whatnot. Any ideas?

[image: Error message received]

[image: diskutil list output]

UPDATE: I verified my disk and got these errors. Attempting to repair but worried that my Snow Leopard disk will overwrite the Lion recovery partition....

[image: Drive errors]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

OK, this isn't too bad. Reboot while holding <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> to enter single user mode. When it gives you a prompt, type

```
fsck -fy
```

then press return. it will repair your disk. When it's done, type

```
reboot
```

and try partitioning again.

Comment: Does this cause any files to be deleted or any data to be lost?

Comment: No, it's the equivalent of clicking the Repair Disk button in Disk Utility.

Comment: This worked on Mavericks for me!

Comment: Just out of curiosity... What makes this work while repair disk (even from the recovery partition) couldn't.

Comment: This worked for me for an external drive, so it's not that files were in use by the OS, as it could be for the main drive.

Comment: thanks for the help. After I fix it, i'm told it's fixed, but then the same error occurred :(

Answer (score 3):

The solution ended up being to create a Lion install disk, boot from the disk, run disk utility repair on the drive and volume, then resize the partition. Easier than I thought it would be.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but this worked for me as well.
I had to make the partition smaller, then resize it larger again for it to work.
And yes it was easier than I thought it would be, too. After I found this post.

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me after receiving the same error:

- Shut down.
- Start up holding down <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. (This will boot you into Single User Mode.)
- At the prompt, type in the command `fsck -fy`.
- When that finishes, type `reboot`.
- Try resizing again in Disk Utility.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and couldn't resolve it this way because I had a 4gb swap drive (ubuntu linux) that needed to be turned off before disk utility could remove it.

Steps:

- boot to to Ubuntu Live CD (I used an EFI boot via usb)
- open gparted via terminal `$ sudo gparted`
- look for a partition with a key symbol on it's same line
- right click the key symbol and select "swap off"
- reboot back to mac then follow steps above

Cheers